# How to insert or update multiple rows in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a large amount of rows using a prepared statement in JDBC, with performance as my key point of concern.

I could easily do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE uuid=incoming_data_uuid` on every single item I want to insert, but this would mean that every single item I'm trying to insert-or-update into the table will need *two* queries to run: a `select` and an (`update` or `insert`). This is not optimal at all, as performance will be lowered significantly due to the number of queries traveling back and forth from client to database.

I've looked at other methods of doing this, including using exception handling, but none of the example I've found contain multiple values.

So, is it possible to somehow do a `INSERT INTO table (?,?,?,?,?) VALUES (), (), (), (), () ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fields` or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you add them to a batch and perform all of them in a single network round trip.

I would do a SELECT INTO if you want to operate on existing data.

Your concern about performance is a good one.